# graphnode with different colors in R using Graphviz

Tags: r, graph, colors, nodes, graphviz

I´m working in R with biological networks. For visualization I use Graphviz. I can color specific nodes with this examplecode:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
library(KEGGgraph)
library("KEGG.db")
tmp <- tempfile()

pName <- "MAPK signaling pathway"

pId <- mget(pName, KEGGPATHNAME2ID)[[1]]

x<-retrieveKGML(pId, organism = "hsa", destfile = tmp, method = "wget",quiet =TRUE)

mapkKGML <- system.file("extdata/hsa04010.xml", package = "KEGGgraph")

mapkG <- parseKGML2Graph(mapkKGML,expandGenes=TRUE)
anz <- nodes(mapkG)[c(1:5,11:25,41:45)]
mapkGsub <- subGraph( anz, mapkG)

library(Rgraphviz)
outs <- sapply(edges(mapkGsub), length) >0
ins <- sapply(inEdges(mapkGsub), length)>0
ios <- outs|ins


if(require(org.Hs.eg.db)){
   ioGeneID <- translateKEGG2GeneID(names(ios))
   nodesNames <- sapply(mget(ioGeneID, org.Hs.egSYMBOL, ifnotfound = NA), "[[",1)
}else{
  nodesNames <- names(ios)
}

names(nodesNames) <- names(ios)

atri                <- getDefaultAttrs()
atri$node$shape     <- "ellipse"
atri$node$label     <- nodesNames
atri$edge$weight    <- "0.3"
atri$edge$minlen    <- "2"
atri$graph$rankdir  <- "LR"
atri$graph$size
atri$graph$nodesep  <- "0.05"
atri$graph$ranksep  <- "0.2"
atri$edge$arrowsize <- "0.4"
atri$node$fontsize  <- "18"
atri$node$height    <- "2"
atri$node$width     <- "3.5"

noAttrs <- list()
noAttrs$label <- nodesNames
noAttrs$label
ncolor <- c("green", "blue")
names(ncolor) = nodes(mapkGsub)[1:2]
noAttrs$fillcolor <- ncolor

png(filename="170524_MAPK_Pathway_FS.png")
 plot(mapkGsub,nodeAttrs=noAttrs,attrs=atri)
dev.off()
```

Here is the result: [MAPK Pathway Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjgvJ.png)
Now I want to color each node with two different colors. I´ve tried to use the attribute colorList 
from Graphviz http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#kcolorList but it don't work for me.
Changing the fillcolor to `'green;0.5:red'` and setting `atri$node$style <- "filled" atri$node$gradientangle <- 0` throws this error

```
Fehler in polygon(x.theta, y.theta, density = NA, border = fg, col = bg,  : 
ungültiger Farbname in 'green;0.5:red'
```

Has anyone expirience with R and Graphviz attributs to explain me the usage for multicolor nodes?

Answer (score 0):

All the aspects of a graphviz graph depend on what is in your .dot file. Here is an example of a .dot file with multiple colors

```
strict graph  {
graph [outputorder=edgesfirst];
"1_1_1"  [color=red,shape=point,width="0.25"];
"2_1_67"     [color=blue,shape=point,width="0.25"];
"1_1_1" -- "2_1_67"  [color=black,len=1];}
```

and here is a snippet of some of the python code one might use to generate this file - in this code, I have a list of nodes and a list of edges, and I have specific data stored in those nodes to determine what their color, as well as several other things, should be

```
import networkx as nx
g=nx.Graph()
for node in nodes:
    splitnode=node.split("_")
    if splitnode[0]=="2":
        g.add_node(node,color='blue',shape='point',width=.1)
    if splitnode[0]=="1":
        g.add_node(node,color='red',shape='point',width=.1)
for edge in edges:
    if labels:
        g.add_edge(edge[0],edge[1],len=edge[2],color='black',label=str(edge[2]))
    else:
        g.add_edge(edge[0],edge[1],len=edge[2],color='black')
nx.drawing.nx_agraph.write_dot(g,'tmp.dot')
```

If you render the above dot file using `neato -Tpng <input> -O` it will produce an image which looks like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3554.png).

I understand that you are working with R and not python, and I'm sorry that I do not know R and cannot answer your question more effectively. The take home point is you need to somehow get the colors of the nodes in your node definitions within your .dot file.

Comment: Thank you, but I have to make my problem clearer. I want to color 1 node with two different colors like the left half form the node is green and the other half is red. The description from the Graphviz website said the attribute colorList accepts multiple colors for each node like in my post.